# Why is the piped async operator causing the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError message in the browser console?

Tags: angular

When using an observable directly in a view as in:

```
<tr *ngFor="let device of devices$ | async">
```

the browser console shows the error:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
```

If instead using a component member variable as in:

```
<tr *ngFor="let device of devices">
```

and defined as in:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.observeDevices();
}
private observeDevices(): void {
  this.devicesSubscription = this.deviceStore.getDevices()
  .subscribe((devices: Array<Device>) => {
    this.devices = devices;
  });
}
```

then the said error does not show up.

The member variables are declared as in:

```
devices$: Observable<Array<Device>>;
devices: Array<Device>;
```

Under `Angular` release `~9.0.6`

UPDATE: To have the view refreshed after a change in the `subscribe()` block, I also had to have an explicit call to the change detection, as in:

```
private observeDevices(): void {
  this.devicesSubscription = this.deviceStore.getDevices()
  .subscribe((devices: Array<Device>) => {
    this.devices = devices;
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

Otherwise, the array in the view would not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the async-pipe if `devices` is an observable. In your code, you explicitly assign an array to it, so you don't need the pipe.

Comment: You may have not seen it, for it was not so obvious maybe, but the `devices*` variable was the observable on arrays of devices. Whereas the `devices` variable was the array of devices.